# DB2: Extract string between 2 specific delimiters

Tags: db2

I am writing a DB2 query for a Crystal Report and am running into an issue.  I have a column in one of my tables that looks like this:

```
VISITOR=123456|ID=789
```

I need to extract the "123456" between the first "=" and the "|" that comes after, for all rows in that column.  I was able to figure out the formula in Crystal, and I think I could accomplish it in SQL, but translating that over to DB2 is proving difficult.  For instance, not being able to use CHARINDEX is a show stopper for me.  Can anyone offer any assistance?  Thanks.

Comment: Check out the Db2 regexp function to extract it.

Comment: Okay, will do.  I was looking at LOCATE but it wasn't really giving me what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [REGEXP_SUBSTR scalar function](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061497.html).

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(T.STR, '[^=]*=([^|]*)|', 1, 1, '', 1)
FROM (
VALUES 
  'VISITOR=123456|ID=789'
, 'str1 = 123456 | str2'
--, 'whatever string'
) T (STR);
```

Comment: Mark, excuse my inexperience; that works well for that specific string, but how would I change it to extract that number from any string structured in that manner from the table in question?

Comment: @Steven Just try whatever strings structured in the same way as in the updated example.